# Delete Empty Rows In Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete empty rows in excel by using below code:

```
iRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol_Exp).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = .Range("A1:F48")
Set Z = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z50")

For i = iRowLast To 10 Step (-1)
    r.Rows(i).Replace What:=Chr(32), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.Rows(i)) = 0 Then Z.Rows(i).Delete
Next
```

I am looking for empty cell and spaces as well and want to delete the row only if all the respective columns are empty or have spaces with out any actual data.

The problem in this code is it is also deleting spaces between data in excel sheet. Please provide suggestion how can I avoid that.

Comment: What is `r` and what is `Z` ?

Comment: I have edited the code and mentioned r and z as well. Those are my own ranges according to my need in which cells I want to check.

Comment: Replace `r.Rows(i).Replace What:=Chr(32), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart` with `r.Rows(i).Formula = Application.Trim(r.Rows(i).Formula)`

Comment: This works fine thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that the cells which have both data and leading/lagging spaces are modified (trimmed), then Siddharth's response is really neat. Another option is to check whether the cell is composed entirely of spaces ... something like ...

```
iRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol_Exp).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = .Range("A1:F48")
Set Z = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z50")

For i = iRowLast To 10 Step (-1)
    'r.Rows(i).Replace What:=Chr(32), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
    For Each vcell In r.Rows(i).Columns
        If Len(Replace(vcell, " ", "")) = 0 Then vcell = ""
    Next

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.Rows(i)) = 0 Then Z.Rows(i).Delete
Next
```

Comment: If there is a space in cell it is not deleting that row. I want the whole row to be deleted if there is no data and have spaces in the cell.

Comment: I tested the code in a cut down context and with my own test data and it works, but without seeing your data set etc I can't tell why its specifically not working for you. Have you run it in debug and checked whether, for example, there are hidden characters (like Alt-Enter or =CHAR(10)) in the data which makes it look like it should work but actually trips up the logic? And given that the code addition simply checks that if a cell is completely comprised of spaces and if so then make it empty ... it shouldn't be too difficult to check. Cheers.